# For Android this is a simple script which i want to modify for touch devices?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, windows-phone-8.1

This is a simple script for double jump but i also want it to respond for the the touches

```
private LlatformerCharacter2D character;
private bool jump;
void Awake () {
    character = GetComponent<LlatformerCharacter2D>();
}

void Update () {
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        jump = true;    
}

void FixedUpdate() {
    character.Move (1, false, jump);
    jump = false;
}
```

Comment: brothers could you please favor me in this thing i am new to c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make a object with a collider and tag it as Jump (this will be your Jump button) and check if it is touched

```
 void Update () {
         if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
              Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
             RaycastHit hit;
              if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)) {
                 if(hit.collider.tag=="Jump")
                     jump = true; 
              }
         }
}
```

Comment: oh thank you so much man. it was that easy thank you so much.